# libyaml-cpp error when using catkin_make on gscam

Tags: c++, gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran across a problem, probably because I deleted one day some files related to libyaml. Anyway when I try to build gscam (ros package) I get this error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libyaml-cpp.so.0.2, needed by /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcamera_calibration_parsers.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcamera_calibration_parsers.so: undefined reference to `YAML::Node::begin() const'
```

And I can't find where I could get it. I mean, I've downloaded 0.3 version from code google yaml-cpp and it works for my purposes. Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/169341/libyaml-cpp-error-when-using-catkin_make-on-gscam/) by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to reinstall the yaml-cpp development library on Ubuntu by running:

On precise:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall yaml-cpp
```

On newer versions of Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libyaml-cpp-dev
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on 2014-05-25**:
I don't have any libyaml-cpp libraries avalaible there.Only some libyaml libraries. I tried installing libyaml-dev but it didn't help.Any suggestions?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-25**:
I'm not sure I understand your comment; what do you mean by "I don't have any libyaml-cpp libraries avalaible there" ? Can you copy and paste the EXACT error message?

**Comment by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on 2014-05-25**:
output: E: Unable to locate package libyaml-cpp-dev

**Comment by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on 2014-05-25**:
And the output after sudo apt-get install libyam TAB TAB
libyaml-0-2             libyaml-dev             libyaml-shell-perl
libyaml-0-2-dbg         libyaml-libyaml-perl    libyaml-syck-perl
libyaml-appconfig-perl  libyaml-perl            libyaml-tiny-perl

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-25**:
Are you running ROS on Ubuntu or a different OS?

**Comment by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on 2014-05-25**:
Ubuntu 12.04

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-25**:
Ah, ok. I'm using a newer version of Ubuntu. It looks like the appropriate package on 12.04 is yaml-cpp . If you still can't find it, check to make sure that the ROS repository is still enabled.

**Comment by [delta785](https://answers.ros.org/users/13666/delta785/) on 2014-05-25**:
Aaaand that solved the problem. Many thanks!